# VisualStudio, Bookmark broken after relocating project to new directory

Tags: visual-studio, development-environment

When I renamed the root directory of my project, the bookmarks in VisualStudio still point to the old directory. **How can I make the bookmarks point to the new location?**

Where are the bookmarks stored?, are they editable?

I am using VisualStudio2012